# Use a custom server for Node.js

Tags: node.js

I recently made a amazing server in C#, and was curious if it was a good idea to use my custom C# server instead of making a server in Node.js. I prefer to use the C#, but I don't see the point if I can make one in node.js.

-Is it a good idea to use my server instead of making one in Node.Js?

-If I use Node.js, which module(s) should I use to set up sub-domains for my web application?

Comment: Usually domain management is done at a higher level than node, such as nginx or apache, though it certainly can be done with node.

Comment: A higher level, you mean a more advance server. Correct?

Comment: no,  higher-level as in higher in the process chain. before node is reached. nginx gets the request, then routes it based on domain name port and path, rather than node getting the request and routing it based on the same. Having nginx do it allows you to have multiple processes on your server using the same domain/port externally, and also is more able to take care of things such as serving static assets.

Comment: So in order for me to do sub-domains, I need to install a third party program?

Comment: no, you don't have to. but that's how it's usually done. Node, or C#, can take care of all of it, but, why re-invent the wheel when there's a tool out there that already handles all of the ins and outs of that task.

Comment: I am doing this mostly to learn

Comment: Isn't asking for a module that would do it for you pretty much the same as asking for another application that would do it for you? you'd likely learn more useful skills using best practices rather than building something you'd rarely ever use in the real world.

Comment: But, here's a list of relevant modules: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=sub+domain